# Line Breaks EPSON RC+

Tags: industrial-robot

Maybe this question belongs on StackOverflow, but it's a robotics software specific question so I wasn't sure.

Is there any way to cut a super long line in two in EPSON RC+ 7.4.8? The SPEL + syntax is pretty similar to VBA where you can use " _ " to stop a line and continue it on the next line, but I cannot find mention of any such character in any of the manuals.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge for the maximum line length for SPEL is 512 characters and there is no line continue character.